# Monitoring CPU usage of 2 JVMs running on a single machine

Tags: java, monitoring, cpu-usage

I have two JVMs running on a single machine. I am able to monitor the CPU usage of every single JVM using jConsole but now I have a different scenario.

I also need CPU usage of both JVMs combined. This would give me graph that will show the CPU usage of both JVMs combined.

Can anyone suggest me some tool that could give me the desired result?

Also, I should be able to specify the 2 JVMs for which I need combined results as there could be more than 2 JVMs running simultaneously on the machine.

Comment: Can you run the two programs in the same JVM?

Comment: Not possible...This is product requirement / architecture that both the things should run on different jvm's.

Comment: So this cannot be done even for testing purposes?  Also you can't run the JVMs on a machine or virtual machine by themselves?

Comment: No we can't do this for testing also reason for that being this is integral part of product architecture and would require a lot of changes.

Comment: So I assume you have no way of unit testing this configuration ;) Can you use a lone real/virtual machine to run them both.

Answer (score 1):

JConsole uses `JMX` to get the CPU usage from the JVMs. You can write your own `JMX` client which find this info from the required JVMs directly and combine them (and show them in a graph or something).

Answer (score 0):

[jvmtop](http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop) shows you all (accessible) jvms and there cpu/memory usage in a top-like manner.